# Start animation after ImageView are loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have added an animation to a `Fragment` transition, but said `Fragment` has 2 `ImageViews` with 2 listeners attached to them, therefore the first loading of the `Fragment` hides the animation, but the next one works properly.

Here is how I do my animation:

```
public void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = TrakrActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction().addToBackStack("AboutFragment");

    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_animation,
            R.anim.stay, R.anim.stay, R.anim.exit_animation).replace(R.id.content_frame,
            fragment, "KEY").commit();
}
```

How may I start this animation only after my `ImageViews` are loaded in order to have a smooth UX?

EDIT:

My images are added manually to my `.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/picture_layout"
    android:layout_below="@id/email_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/picture_layout_height"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/email_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/dev_buy_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/picture_layout_height">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/github_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/pictures_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/github_logo"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/linkdin_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/pictures_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/linkedin_logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nobody knows how you *load your ImageViews*

Comment: They are added manually in my `.xml` file.

Comment: then show that `.xml` file

Comment: ok, and you say that they are shown after animation starts?

Comment: No, the animation does not occur on the first loading. When I only display `TextView`s, the animation occurs normally.